# if cell cant be found in other workbook then delete row

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

what I've got is two workbooks, and currently if the cells in the slave workbook equal that in the master it copies certain data out. Also if it cant be found but one column equals yes it will add it to the end.
However what I would like is if it cant be found in the master but exists in the slave, to delete it from the salve workbook.
Below is what I have so far:

```
Dim bolFound As Boolean
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim fpath As String
Dim owb As Workbook

Dim Master As Worksheet 'declare both
Dim Slave As Worksheet

fpath = "\\calum\Work\mastersheet.xlsm"
Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath) 'open location and file

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary") 'sheet from workbook im in
Set Slave = owb.Worksheets("Schedule") 'sheet in workbook im copying too
'
Let x = 0
Do While x < 2 'loop through twice so it can add new data

lngLastRow = Slave.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1 'find last row
For j = 1 To 1000 '(the master sheet)
bolFound = False
For i = 1 To 1000 '(the slave sheet) 'for first 1000 cells
    If Trim(Master.Cells(j, 2).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'if ID cell is blank jump to last line
    If Master.Cells(j, 2).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 1).Value And _
        Master.Cells(j, 65).Value = "Yes" Then
            Slave.Cells(i, 5).Value = Master.Cells(j, 18).Value & ", " & Master.Cells(j, 19).Value & ", " & Master.Cells(j, 20).Value & ", " & Master.Cells(j, 22).Value 'If the ID equals that in the slave sheet and there is a yes ticked the copy address
            Slave.Cells(i, 8).Value = Master.Cells(j, 5).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 10).Value = Master.Cells(j, 31).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 11).Value = Master.Cells(j, 33).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 12).Value = Master.Cells(j, 7).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 13).Value = Master.Cells(j, 30).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 15).Value = Master.Cells(j, 34).Value

            bolFound = True

    End If
Next
If bolFound = False And _
    Master.Cells(j, 65).Value = "Yes" Then
        Slave.Cells(lngLastRow, 1).Value = Master.Cells(j, 2).Value  'adding the new entry to the list
        lngLastRow = lngLastRow + 1
Else
 Slave.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete 'not sure how to delete row if bolfound=false and it isn't in the master?

         End If



Next
x = x + 1
Loop
```

Comment: What does your current code do? How is it different from what you want it to do? Does it error, or does it simply not perform?

Comment: hi, it basically deletes every single row in the slave sheet at present.

Comment: without the delete bit it works perfectly fine, can add rows, can update information when data is matching, its just when trying to delete the row if ID in column A mastersheet isn't found in column A slave sheet.

Comment: Without going too deep into your workbook, are you sure you want a Do While loop with 2 nested IF loops? My guess is that it keeps on looping, changing values, and deleting, when you would otherwise want the Do While loop to end early - but I haven't confirmed this.

Comment: The reason I added a do while was simply because when a row was added (if yes) it would only add the ID to column A so I used a do loop to loop through again and then add the data the same as the others on all the other columns, I know its pretty messy but was a temp fix

Comment: "There is nothing more permanent than a temporary solution." Keep your workbook clean when you code it the first time. If you don'thave the patience to keep it clean when it is fresh in your mind, I promise you that you will never go back and change it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet unfortunately but wouldn't it be easier to delete a row using `Rows(i).Delete` ?

For `Slave.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete` *i* will always be 1 or 1000?!
Your problem is somewhere in what *i* is when it deletes this row...which if it is 1 and does this for 1000 loops of *j* would deleted all data.

Might want an else while type statement here to check for `bolfound = false` before deleting.

Best advice I can give without building it out.

Comment: Hi Ross, so your suggest something like "else while bolfound= false rows(i).delete? Just abit confused?

Comment: If you only wanted to delete while boldfound = false then yeah you would need that in there and you could also add the and statement to check if it is in the master.  Did you check for the value of *i* when it gets to the else `Slave.Cells(i,1).EntireRow.Delete` is taking place? I'm thinking it is one of the above values, and if it is 1 that would be why it is deleting all the rows in `Slave`.

Comment: The value of _i_ is 1001 at that point, i need it to basically say if it can't be found then delete row, simply in plain text harder on vba.

Comment: `If IsEmpty(Slave.Cells(i,1).Value) = True Then
     Slave.Cells(i,1).EntireRow.Delete
   End If`        -? You could also add And _ if you needed more conditionals.  Is that what you are kinda looking for?  I'm still fuzzy on what exactly the program is trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Ross, excuse my late reply, basically the code is comparing two arrays from different workbooks, if the ID In master sheet equals ID in slave sheet then it copies the row. However what I'm looking for is if the row has been removed in the master for whatever reason but its still in the slave, then to delete it from the slave? does that make sense?